# displaying user input from edit text to list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have problem with adding 2 numbers in list view. This is my row with 2 text view (for each numer). textView2 ignore

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" - "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When user add number it will display in list view. That second number needs to be 11 - that number that user inserted. It's all working but I dont know how to display that second number.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> m_adapter;
    ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button bt;
    EditText et;
    TextView tv;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
                m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row, R.id.textView1);
                lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
                //final String input = et.getText().toString();

                bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String input = et.getText().toString();
                        if(null!=input&&input.length()>0){     
                        String maxpunti = "11";
                        int a = Integer.parseInt(maxpunti);
                        int b = Integer.parseInt(input);
                        int c = a-b;
                        String input2 = String.valueOf(c);
                        m_adapter.add(input);
                        m_adapter.add(input2);
                        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                      }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of  ArrayAdapter<String> binds a single Stringvalue to a a single textfield. Since you have several views for each listitem or "row" in your listview ( you need to implement/extend your own ArrayAdapter and override the getView method.
Them you can set the values for any number of custom views that you may have in your list item layout.

Look at [a simple example](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/) and also it might be a good idea to look som docs on how listviews/adpters work in android since they are very central.